# How do I put this into a variable?

Tags: php, variables, loops, while-loop

```
$now = time();
while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]        
['name']))
 {
$now++;
 }
```

Does anybody know how to put this into a variable so i can insert the result into a database?

EDIT:

Sorry, to be a bit clearer:

I need the image filename thats is generated from this while loop into a variable so i can insert that into the database.

for example if i were to upload a file called 'mypic.png' it becomes:

1335367953-mypic.

This is the string i need in a variable.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what the intent is. Could you explain what you are trying to accomplish, where the file came from and *all* the processes you wish to accomplish in this script?

Comment: Hi, Basically, i am trying to upload an image to a folder on the server. All works fine. But for a different part of the app i need to link to the image and all I need is the image filename after it has been generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
basename($uploadFilename);
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the filename in a variable, `$uploadFilename`.

**Edit after clarification**

You can create a variable to hold just the filename, then when you check it, include the $uploadsDirectory.

```
$now = time();
$filename = $now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]        
['name'])
while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory . $filename))
 {
    $now++;
    $filename = $now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]        
 }
```

Comment: Yeah but for some reason this adds: /var/chroot/home/content/70/8226070/html/website/testtest/uploader/uploaded_files/1335369533-myid.png ?